# fullcalendar eventClick start time not formatting correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

In my fullcalendar eventClick I'm fetching the start time and formatting it, but the formatted time isn't returning correctly. Instead of 7:30:00 AM I'm getting 12:00:00 AM. Funny thing is it's happening on the second and third, etc, etc, time I click on the event. The first time returns the correct formatted time.

Here is my code and a screen shot of what I'm getting back

```js
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
  var t = calEvent.start.format('h:mm:ss A');
}
```

Here is what the ide is returning

[image]

One last thing I noticed is _ambigTime: true on the second event click and false on this first. Would this have changed something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to correctly format the time, like this:

```
event.start.format("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: tried this! 'HH' is for 24 hour time. Not what I want!

Comment: the issue is happening on the 2nd or 3rd time I click on the event. The first time comes back ok, but the second time I click on the event, I see the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was stripping off the time after I formatted it.

calEvent.start.stripTime();